# Parent Activity with fragments shows blank screen occassionally

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on a application which has Single activity rest all fragments...
This issue i'm facing occurs occasionally.. like when ever i press back button from any of the fragment the previous fragment appears... but sometimes it happens that My activity shows blank screen with action bar present, and rest of the screen is blank instead of showing the fragment... Since this issue appears occasionally i'm not able to debug it also... Any idea why it happens so??
Here is the code fragment transaction..

```
    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, int activityNumber) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trnx = manager.beginTransaction();

    trnx.replace(R.id.fragPage, fragment, "Current_Fragment");

    if (activityNumber != FragmentActivityNumbers.HOME_ORDERNUM) {
        trnx.addToBackStack(null);


    }
    trnx.commit();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Don't use `replace` the first time. Use `trnx.add()` method when adding a fragment for the first time.

Comment: @IshitaSinha the first fragment is login screen when the app is installed for the first time... and i dont want that to be displayed from second time user launches the app... so from second time Home screen fragment will be the first fragment... Will it work if i Just replace trnx.replace() by trnx.add() for all the fragment

Comment: If you do `trnx.add()` for all the fragments, the backstack might not work properly. Of course, you can always test it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to test if its the first fragment so you use Add instead of replace then you can use replace for the others fragments .